# No sound on headphones - Asus GL703GE-ES73

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, today audio was gone when using my headphone jack. Speakers still work. Connected a USB DAC and it also works in there. Also tried a USB Headset, also works. Problem is just on the mini-plug jack.

Ran "alsactl restore" and got this error:

```
vallo@vallo-Strix-17-GL703GE:~$ alsactl restore
alsactl: state_lock:125: file /var/lib/alsa/asound.state lock error: File exists
alsactl: load_state:1683: Cannot open /var/lib/alsa/asound.state for reading: File exists
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Realtek ALC295" "HDA:10ec0295,10431bc0,00100002 HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000" "0x1043" "0x1bc0"
```

Hardware is initialized using a generic method

I have dual boot, when I boot on Windows audio works as expected.

Tried editing `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and appending  `options snd-hda-intel model=auto` at the end but nothing changed. Tried several values for `model` but none made the trick.

Tried reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio but nothing worked.

My laptop is a Asus Strix GL703GE-ES73.

`sudo dmesg | grep snd`:

```
vallo@vallo-Strix-17-GL703GE:~$ sudo dmesg | grep snd
[    4.385259] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: dmic_detect option is deprecated, pass snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 option instead
[    4.385278] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.603865] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    4.665884] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for Generic: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    4.665887] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.665889] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.665890] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    4.665891] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    4.665893] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x12
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is caused by a kernel update that is bugged. Found this workaround:

> paste this line “options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mode” into file
> “/etc/modprobe.d/alsa.conf” then SHUTDOWN the system, DO NOT reboot.
> Then turn on the system and the sound should appear, but the
> microphone in the headphones will probably no longer work.

In my case, microphone still works.

Info found [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/sound-from-speakers-no-sound-from-3-5mm-jack-audio/5343/19)